# Kotlin/Corda/SpringBoot application causing SLF4J StackOverflowError

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, log4j, slf4j, corda

I'm not entirely sure why this has stopped working. My project was working a few weeks ago, but I've just tried to run it again and I'm just getting a StackOverflowError with respect to logging

The application I'm running isn't causing this because I've replaced the main method with something empty:

```
class Application {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(vararg args: String) {
            println("Hello, world.");
        }
    }
}
```

Getting the following error in the console (I've chopped out most of it because it's just a repetition of what's causing the StackOverflowError):

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.11.2/4d44e4edc4a7fb39f09b95b09f560a15976fa1ba/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocator.getCallerClass(StackLocator.java:121)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocatorUtil.getCallerClass(StackLocatorUtil.java:55)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext.getLogger(SLF4JLoggerContext.java:39)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.newLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.newLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext.getLogger(SLF4JLoggerContext.java:39)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.newLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.newLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext.getLogger(SLF4JLoggerContext.java:39)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.newLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.newLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
```

These are my gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    // Main
    implementation "$kotlin_group:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "$corda_group:corda-core:$corda_release_version"
    implementation "$corda_group:corda-rpc:$corda_release_version"
    implementation "$springboot_group:spring-boot-starter-web:$springboot_release_version"

    implementation "$newco_group:newco-kotlin-core:$newco_kotlin_core_release_version"
    implementation "$newco_group:newco-kotlin-libex:$newco_libex_release_version"
    implementation "$newco_group:newco-kotlin-libex-services:$newco_libex-services_release_version"
    implementation "$newco_group:newco-corda-fintex-contract:$newco_fintex_release_version"
    implementation "$newco_group:newco-corda-fintex-workflow:$newco_fintex_release_version"
    implementation "$newco_group:newco-corda-fintex-integration:$newco_fintex_release_version"

    implementation project(":cordapp-contract")
    implementation project(":cordapp-workflow")
    implementation project(":cordapp-integration")

    // Test
    testRuntimeOnly "$junit_group:junit-jupiter-engine:$junit_version"
    testImplementation "$junit_group:junit-jupiter-api:$junit_version"
    testImplementation "$kotlin_group:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation "$corda_group:corda-node-driver:$corda_release_version"
}
```

I've tried adding this to gradle but to no avail:

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
        exclude module: 'jms'
        exclude module: 'jmxtools'
        exclude module: 'jmxri'
    }
}
```

Any ideas? - I have no idea where to start

Comment: Try to view dependency tree to find out multiple jar location, then exclude from one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an infinite loop when initializing the logging interfaces & implementation, which is causing the StackOverflowError.

You have multiple log bindings on your classpath, as seen in the log output:

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.

Excluding either log4j or logback from your dependencies should fix your issue.

Make sure that you use the correct exclude reference. Based on the log output, I think you should exclude `log4j-slf4j-impl` instead of `slf4j-log4j12` (or something along those lines).

Comment: Worked first time. Thank you.